# Stopping an Index Reorganize job

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2008-r2

Will it be okay if I stop a currently running INDEX Reorganize job on SQL Server 2008 R2? Will there be any problems on the database with such action? Because I was blamed for the slow SQL Server mainly because I stopped a running index reorganize job. And I'm not sure if it was the real cause of the slow Sql server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Will it be okay if I stop a currently running INDEX Reorganize job on Sql Server 2008 R2? Will there be any problems on the database with such action?

No there wont be any such harm when you stop the index reorganize job. Index reorganize jobs can be interrupted and can be resumed later at favorable time. I cannot say that index reorganize job was the reason for slowness because for me its a light activity. Of course depending on database size it can be massive.

Reorganize only requires 8KB of additional space in the database

Reorganize is always single-threaded so can be slow

Reorganize is always fully logged so it does affect transaction log growth but does not  prevent transaction log truncation

Reorganize does not holds blocking locks

You can safely stop it but you need to find out why your database became slow.

As a generally accepted good practice reorganize only when ragmentation of index is between 5 to 30 % for anything more than that rebuild the index.

> Because I was blamed for the slow SQL Server mainly because I stopped a running index reorganize job

Now you have to find from your side that whether database is slow because of the job or is slow due to other reason. Its difficult to believe that index reorganize can slow things much although I have seen blockings but nothing to impact much